# WPF Dataset DataGrid Foreign Key Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have two tables in a dataset:

```
Schedules
-------------
id INT
schedule_date DATETIME
service_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES services(id)

Services
-------------
id INT
name VARCHAR
```

I can easily bind a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` and get the result I want in the following way:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Service" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource schedulesDataSet}, Path=services}"
    DisplayMemberPath="name"
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=service_id}" 
    SelectedValuePath="id" />
```

But how do I do it with a `DataGridTemplateColumn`? I want to do this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Service" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=services.name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But as I am using a Dataset and not Entity Framework, I guess that's why it doesn't work.

What's the right way to do it?

### EDIT:

Complete DataGrid code:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource schedulesViewSource}}">
    <DataGrid Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" Name="schedulesDataGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=schedule_date,StringFormat=dd-MMM-yy,ConverterCulture=da-DK}" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Service" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=services.name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Status" Width="*" x:Name="scheduleStatusColumn" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ScheduleStatuses}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Source" Binding="{Binding Path=done_by}" Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: can you post your complete datagrid code?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Okay, I did

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.itemssource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for your DataGrid

```
   <DataGrid Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding schedulesViewSource, Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" Name="schedulesDataGrid">
```

Comment: Why would I do that? The DataContext is already set in the Grid and the binding for the rest of the columns already works fine.

Comment: @mtwell , you have not mentioned that in question, ok wait

Comment: Sorry but doesn't work. The path "name" doesn't exist in this table and has to be gotten from the foreign key table.